# Stop execution without quitting console

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

Does anyone know how to stop program execution without exiting the R console? I could just call `q("no")` but am actually looking for something similar to a throws statement to stop the execution, but leave the console active. Return?

Comment: What... those aren't constructive comments.

Comment: Install the **fortunes** package. Both of those will reveal witty comments from R-help mailing list referencing `stop()`, which is the answer you accepted. Not un-constructive, just overly witty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [stop](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/stop.html) function:

```
stop()
```